# What happened on Dec 31 1969 at 7:00 PM

Tags: php, date, history

Every time in PHP when I make a variable such as this one:

```
$date = strtotime($row['date']);
$date = date("M d Y \a\\t g:i A", $date); // Mmm dd YYYY at h:mm PM/AM
```

and somehow `row['date']` happens to be 0, the date `Dec 31 1969 at 7:00 PM` is displayed on the screen? Google does not tell me much, I was wondering if this date had any significances.

Comment: On the one hand you have `epic` bugs, on the other you have `epoch` bugs :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The Unix epoch is the time 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970.  This is the reference point for all time stamps.  When you use PHP's date/time functions, you're always working with the number of seconds since the epoch.  Time 0 is the epoch, and you (or your web server) must be on the east coast of the US, which is 5 hours behind UTC time.

Comment: i guess the same applies to the europe time zone?

Comment: @Wollhaar Sure, the same concepts apply to all time zones. Europe has multiple time zones, ranging from UTC+0 to UTC+3 (i believe).

Comment: ah ok, thought first the timestamp follows the time anywhere in the us timezone... but when it is on the UTC time then i understand that way. but then i should now 2hours after the UTC layin. But it is´nt...  i get a cookie filled with an timestamp from 1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z 
and that´s a bit awkward

Answer (score 31):

I find it funny that not a single response here attempted to answer your actual question, which was (if I can paraphrase) "What is the significance of the actual date of Unix epoch time"?

I'm not an expert on the subject but basically, as I understand it, the concept of epoch time was invented in 1971.  The programmers chose the arbitrary date of January 1, 1971 GMT to be epoch time.  This was partly due to the fact that older computers couldn't handle large numbers so the date had to be in the recent past.  Afterwards, epoch time was adjusted to be Jan 1, 1970 so as to be a nice, round number.

So basically, nothing "happened" on that date.  It was an arbitrary date chosen based on the original time of the work being done.

Answer (score 6):

[Unix timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) are measured in "time since the [Unix Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch#Encoding_time_as_a_number)", which is Midnight GMT at the end of Dec. 31 1969 (a.k.a. 00:00 GMT Jan 1 1970). Since you appear to be on Eastern Standard Time, which is GMT-5, you get 7pm Dec. 31st 1969 for a unix timestamp value of 0.

Answer (score 4):

Let me guess: you live on the east coast of the USA?

PHP, like many other systems uses the [Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch) to measure time, i.e. a value of 0 represents  January 1, 1970, midnight UTC - which is the same as Dec 31 1969 at 7:00 PM Eastern Standard Time.

Answer (score 1):

One format in which date objects are stored is the time in seconds that have elapsed from an arbitrary start time.  Asking for a formatted version of "0" is like asking for that arbitrary start time.  I don't remember why that date was chosen, but I'm sure Wikipedia does.  See the article on Unix time below.

[Read about Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)