# strtotime giving me intermittently wrong dates

Tags: php

I'm using this;

```
else{
    $tempdate = date('Y/m/d' , strtotime($shipd . " +3 days"));
    $h .= " <td><div title='{$row['VIAHOVER']}'>{$tempdate}</div></td>";
```

And it's displaying some of the dates correctly by adding 3 days to the original date, but some dates are showing 1969/12/31.

How can this work for some but not others when the date info comes from the same place?

Comment: your formatting is wrong somewhere - need to convert your $shipd format to Y-m-d

Comment: http://mentalfloss.com/article/26316/why-does-my-gadget-say-its-december-31-1969

Comment: I can't do that unfortunately because the existing dates are all Y/m/d

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390463/what-happened-on-dec-31-1969-at-700-pm

Comment: So convert the existing dates to a usable format. All you need to do is `$shipd = str_replace('/', '-', $shipd);`

Comment: Your problem is all to do with the american way of expressing dates i.e. starting with the month and not the day. If it see's a `/` as a separator it assumes USA all ass backwards format. But if you are actually using UK format but using the `/` separator sometimes it will get day and month confused

Comment: "all ass backwards" sounds so much better than any ISO-something date format name. Rep.